# how to output dots/arrows at the ends of line

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot, I need to plot my data and display a small circle or an arrow at each end of the line chart. how can I do that?
I use this command to display the line chart:

```
plot 'data.txt' with lines
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to make lines have something at the end automatically, but I found a workaround.  With this data file:

```
1 1
2 3
3 2
```

and the following script:

```
set term png
set out 'plot.png'

stats 'data.dat' name 'a'
# plot line, then circle only if it is the last data point
plot 'data.dat' t 'data', \
     '' u ($0==(a_records-1)?$1:1/0):2 with points pt 7 ps 2 t 'end'
```

I can make a plot like this:

[image]

The `stats` command is to find the number of data points, then the dual plot command draws the line connecting the data points, then a circle only on the last data point (determined with the `a_records` variable.  An arrow would be trickier to draw...

To find more info about different point/line style options, the `test` command at the gnuplot command line is your friend.